# Jquery усовершенствовать выборку

Tags: jquery

Имееются блоки

```
<div><h1>Текст заголовока</h1></div>
<div><h1>Текст заголовока<b> жирный текст</b></h1></div>
```

Хочу добится чтобы к каждому текстовому тэгу добавлялся класс text.

Тектовый тэг это тэг который имеет в значении только текст, максимум иконку **< i >**

Мой код:

```
$(':not(:has(*),:empty)').addClass('text');
```

Работает только для первого **h1**, а вот для второго добавляет только на тэг **b**
Как усовершенствовать выборку jquery в моем примере? Так же хочу уточнить что тэги могут быть любые как span или p, не суть)
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: `$("h1").addClass('text');`

Comment: Дайте определение для термина: _текстовый тег_. И определитесь на какие именно элементы вы хотите добавлять класс.

Comment: @Grundy , я писал что тэг может быть любой, код не должен зависить от одного конкретного тэга

Comment: _Тектовый тэг это тэг который имеет в значении только текст, максимум иконку < i >_ - таким образом - второй h1 - не текстовый тег, так как `<b>` это не `<i>` следовательно работает так как вы и хотите

Comment: @Grundy , небольшая поправка, текстовые тэги тоже могут быть в тексте, имею ввиду b,span,p,strong,small и т.д, такие тэги которые могут быть вложены в текст

Comment: самый просто вариант просто их перечислить. Вообще в идеале пример входной разметки отхватывающей большинство вариантов(лучше всего все), и пример ожидаемого выхода. иначе остается непонятным какая именно разметка ожидается в конце

Comment: @Grundy как их можно перечислить в моем примере? Учитывая что тэги буду внутри текстовых тэгов?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35358/discussion-between-grundy-and-sdafs-fasafs).